# How can I remove the excess spacing between vertical tabs in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Right now I have a tabControl with these specifications:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="0,0,0,20" Name="TCMainWindow" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Height="502" Width="938">
            <TabItem Header="Import" Name="Import" Margin="0,-2,0,-7">
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Export" Name="Export" Margin="0,70,0,-87" RenderTransformOrigin="0.576,-2.45">
           </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

This gives a chunk of white space between tabs. How do I remove the spacing between tabs?

I noticed that if I removed RenderTransformOrigin from the second TabItem and I manually moved it up closer to the first tab, there's still spacing between tabs.

I suppose my question is really, how do I have no spacing between the first and second vertical tabs? I don't want any space to show. Is this possible?

Comment: if you dont need space then remove margin from tabitem.like this   <TabItem Header="Import" Name="Import"/>
<TabItem Header="Export" Name="Export"/>

Comment: Additionally to what Heena said, also remove **RenderTransformOrigin** (really, i am not sure what you tried there...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *explicitly set Top margin to 70 on second tabItem*. Remove that and it will move up. Moreover, why do you need negative margins altogether.

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="0,0,0,20" Name="TCMainWindow" 
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
            Height="502" Width="938">
    <TabItem Header="Import" Name="Import">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Export" Name="Export" RenderTransformOrigin="0.576,-2.45">
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Okay that works but I have a question. If I want the tabItem to by a certain size, let's say 50x50px and the other tab to be also 50x50px instead of the skinny standard tab without adding the margins, how do I keep a fixed nonstandard tab size without affecting the spacing?

Comment: Set `Height` of the `TabItem`. `<TabItem Header="Export"  Height="50"/>`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. One more n00b question, I specified the height but how do I center the header in the tab control? Thanks again!!

Comment: @KalaJ, in your TabControl set `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` (currently it is "Top").